# Can Azure SQL data warehouse (Synapse Analytics) be installed in on-premise?

Tags: azure-synapse

To store and analyze private data, can Azure Synapse Analytics be installed in their bare metal? i.e. an Azure SQL data warehouse installed in private infrastructure.

Comment: There is Parallel Data Warehouse.  You could also install SQL Server 2019 with some really powerful kit.  It’s SMP not MPP but supports columnstore indexes and big data clusters.  Depends what you need it for.

Answer (score 1):

No.

---

I tried to find some source to quote, but hard to prove a negative. Only things you would find that you can download and install are tools/SDKs to connect to DB/Workspaces in cloud for development, not DB itself.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is NO.  Azure is not just VMs running in the cloud so how would you expect to run a PaaS system on-premises?

In saying that, you do have options.  The on-premises version of a MPP data engine is [Microsoft APS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/sql-server/analytics-platform-system?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259).  This requires specific hardware and is expensive, but gives the same MPP experience as Synapse Dedicated Pools.

[Big Data Clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/big-data-cluster-overview?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15) may also help to implement what you need. This runs on a Kubernetes cluster which you can easily run on-premises.

Finally - the true way to run Azure PaaS services on-premises WILL be [Azure Arc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/azure-arc/data/overview?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259).  I say **WILL BE** as it is still preview and currently only enables Azure SQL Managed Instance and PostgreSQL Hyperscale. There is no guarantee that Synapse will ever be enabled on this platform and if it does come it is still a long way off.

If you are **only** concerned with the privacy of data then this can be crafted with attention paid to encryption, data masking, use of Azure Managed Identities and RBAC roles, and the use of [Private Links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-connect-to-workspace-with-private-links?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259) to restrict access to specific VNETs